# Modify the path to index.jsp

Tags: java, web-services

My environment is spring 4.0 and tomcat 7

I have a index.jsp file in my project under webapp, if I run the project on tomcat

locathost:8080/contextPath_Of_Project/, by default, the browser will display index.jsp

If I want the browser to display index.jsp under localhost:8080/contextPath_of_Project/something/

Is there any solution beside using controller and viewresolver?

can I accomplish the goal by modifying the configuration only?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Modify the Deployment Descriptor file `WEB-INF/web.xml`. Add a welcome-file-list tag below web-app. Your configuration file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>something/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

This sample is based on Java EE 5. You may have to change it if your version is different.